# Transistor problem

Tags: transistors, current, homework

I am very new at transistors. How can i solve this problem?
[image]

Comment: Do you know the current amplifier model of the transistor? Do you know what Beta is?

Comment: collector current equals base current times beta

Comment: Correct. Now try to set up the equations for the current loops. That should give you an idea how to continue.

Comment: i don't know how to set up equations. could you write them?

Comment: It's fairly simple, you should see that the voltage Vbb drops over Rb+Re + Base-emitter-diode. The only additional thing you need to know is how large the voltag drop on Re will be (you already wrote how to use beta). Now show us your best shot on how to calculate Ib. If there is a mistake, we can solve that together ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Well, we have the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fagF1B.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When analyzing a transistor we need to use the following [relations](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transistor/tran_2.html):

- $$\text{I}_\text{E}=\text{I}_\text{B}+\text{I}_\text{C}\tag1$$
- Transistor gain \$\beta\$:
  $$\beta=\frac{\text{I}_\text{C}}{\text{I}_\text{B}}\tag2$$
- Base-emitter voltage:
  $$\text{V}_\text{BE}=\text{V}_1-\text{V}_3\tag3$$

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff's_current_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$\text{I}_\text{E}=\text{I}_\text{B}+\text{I}_\text{C}\tag4$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_\text{E}=\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_\text{C}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{y}-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_\text{B}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{x}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_3}
\end{cases}\tag5
$$

---

Using your values, you need to solve the following system of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
100=\frac{\text{I}_\text{C}}{\text{I}_\text{B}}\\
\\
\text{I}_\text{E}=\text{I}_\text{B}+\text{I}_\text{C}\\
\\
\text{I}_\text{E}=\frac{\text{V}_3}{200}\\
\\
\text{I}_\text{C}=\frac{24-\text{V}_2}{5}\\
\\
\text{I}_\text{B}=\frac{\frac{127}{10}-\text{V}_1}{300}\\
\\
\frac{7}{10}=\text{V}_1-\text{V}_3
\end{cases}\tag6
$$